# Show that int $S$ is an open set

Tags: real-analysis

The following question is from Lay's Analysis with Introduction to Proof, 4th edition:

> Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}$. Show that $\operatorname{int} S$ is an open set.

My work so far: Let $T = \operatorname{int} S$. Then, for every $x \in T$ there exists $\epsilon > 0$ s.t. $N(x;\epsilon) \subset S$.

I'm not sure how to go from here, I need to show that either $\operatorname{int} T = T$ or that bd $T \subset \mathbb{R} - T$

Comment: What's S? Some more context would help.

Comment: show that the open ball is open

Comment: $\text{int} S:=\bigcup\{U\subset S: S\in \mathcal{T}\}$ i.e., is the union of all the open sets contained in $S$. A topology is closed under arbitrary unions of open sets. So $\text{int} S$ is open.

Comment: @Alex H. $S$ is an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @GastónBurrull That is not the definition I was given. My textbook says that int $S$ is the set of all points that have some epsilon neighborhood contained completely in S, i.e., there exists $\epsilon >0 : N(x;\epsilon) \subset S$.

Comment: The definition you gave me would not help as I would have to prove that was true first. That would most likely be harder than the original question

Comment: What is your definition of open?

Comment: @JoseAntonio $\operatorname{int} T = T$ or bd $T \subset \mathbb{R} - T$

Comment: @Toxicz: sorry I missed the int in your question. You should probably edit your question and add your definitions of int S and open sets

Comment: This seems like the best way, I'm lost as how you completed the second inclusion though, why would $x \in U$ imply that there is an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood contained in $U$. I recommend that you answer this comment in a question so that I may accept it.

Comment: Because it was a mistake, I would correct it, but someone else answer your question.  :)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $T = \operatorname{int} S$. We need to show for every $x \in T$, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ s.t. $\forall y\in N(x;\epsilon)$ in an interior point of  $S$.

Let $x \in T$, there exists $r > 0$ s.t. $N(x;r) \subset S$. let $y\in N(x;r)$, set $\epsilon= r-d(x,y)>0$ . We show $N(y;\epsilon) \subset N(x;r) \subset S$. If you can show it, $y \in T$

$z \in N(y;\epsilon)$, i.e. $d(y,z)<\epsilon$, then $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)<r$

If you are assuming standard metric on $\mathbb{R}$, just replace every $d(x,y)$ by $|x-y|$

Comment: What is $d(x, y)$? I'm assuming that this is the standard measure $|y - x|$ on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Toxicz It's a metric on $\mathbb{R}$. For your case, it's just absolute value.